# Prevent duplicate entry into vector? C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a program that prompts a user to enter a value. Each value that the user enters gets placed into a vector 'other' which is there only for validation. If a duplicate value has been entered, the user will get a prompt until they enter a unique value.

The main problem I am facing is that for some reason when running the code and printing out the results of the vector, there appears to be a duplicate entry. Could anyone please tell me why that is?

See below for my code:

```
// prompt to continue
cout << "Would you like to continue? [Y]es, [N]o: ";
cin >> toContinue;

while (toContinue == 'Y')
{
    bool isDuplicate = 0;

    // prompt for product no.
    cout << "Please enter product number: ";
    cin >> productB; 

    // Validation check for duplicate entries
    for (size_t i = 0; i < other.size(); i++)
    {
        if (productB == other[i])
            isDuplicate = 1;

        while (isDuplicate == 1)
        {
            cout << "You have already entered this product number!" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter correct product number: ";
            cin >> productB;

            if (productB != other[i])
                other.push_back(productB);

            isDuplicate = 0;
        }
    }
    // prompt to continue
    cout << "Would you like to continue? [Y]es, [N]o: ";
    cin >> toContinue;
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::set` instead.

Comment: You may want to go through your program with a debugger. Hint: What happens when I input `3 4 3`?

Comment: After you detect a duplicate, you ask the user to re-enter. You check this new number against one number entered immediately prior, but not against all previously entered numbers. So say the user enters `1`, then `2`, then `1` again. You detect the duplicate and ask to reenter. They enter `2`, you only check that `2 != 1` and happily add the second `2` to the vector.

Answer (score 3):

While its common to use `std::set` for unique elements, if you function must return a vector for some reasons, I used such approach:

```
std::set<int> my_set;

my_set.insert(1);
my_set.insert(2);
my_set.insert(1);

// ... insert more

std::vector<int> my_vector(my_set.size());
std::copy(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), my_vector.begin());

assert(my_vector.size()==2);
```

Note that the vector `my_vector` will be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Once you enter a duplicate, you let the user re-enter a number; then you check only if the new entered number is the same as the duplicate entered before; but you do not check if the user entered a different but still duplicate value.

Generally, you mix user input with program logic; unbundling this makes the code more readable and less error prone. See, for example, the following fragments showing how one could separate these concerns:

```
bool isContained(const vector<int> &v, int value) {
   // your code to check for duplicates goes here
}

int main() {

   ...

   while (toContinue == 'Y')  {

      // prompt for product no.
      cout << "Please enter product number: ";
      cin >> productB; 

      if (isContained(other, productB)) {
        cout << "You have already entered this product number!" << endl;
      }
      else {
        other.push_back(productB);
      } 

      // prompt to continue
      cout << "Would you like to continue? [Y]es, [N]o: ";
      cin >> toContinue;
   }
}
```

Also a general hint: using appropriate data structures can also help to avoid unnecessary lines of codes; A container avoiding duplicates, for example, is `std::set`.

Answer (score 1):

You can help yourself a great deal by breaking up the components of your logic into smaller functions.

Most of what I have done here is tidy up, but note the encapsulation of the `contains` function.

```
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool contains(std::vector<int> const& vals, int val)
{
    return std::count(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals), val) != 0;
}

bool shouldContinue()
{
    char toContinue;
    cout << "Would you like to continue? [Y]es, [N]o: ";
    cin >> toContinue;
    return toContinue == 'Y';
}

int getProduct(bool again)
{
    int productB;
    if (again)
    {
        cout << "You have already entered this product number!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Please enter correct product number: ";
    cin >> productB;
    return productB;
}

void printProducts(std::vector<int> const& vals)
{
    std::cout << "You have selected:";
    const char* sep = " ";
    for(int p : vals)
    {
        std::cout << sep << p; 
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> other;

    while (shouldContinue())
    {
        int productB = getProduct(false);
        while(contains(other, productB))
        {
            productB = getProduct(true);
        }
        other.push_back(productB);
    }

    printProducts(other);
}
```